# как при запросе скрыть порт 3000

Tags: python, django, api, dns

есть некое api подключенное к серверу, пример: http://dev.front.python.by:3000/, как сделать так чтоб при запросе не было видно этого порта?

Comment: запустить сервис на 80 порту, а не на 3000